# Help understanding the residue classes and the characteristics of a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Good day, please help understand the following, as I am feeling my self an idiot and not able to figure out what to do:

The study is in a closed algebraic field K.

I have $(x,y)/(x^{2},xy,y^{2},(x-a)^{3}-(y-b)^{2})$

when $a=b=0$ then the previous expression becomes $$(\bar{x},\bar{y})$$ where $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ represent the residue classes of x,y.

When $a\neq0,b\neq0$, the expression becomes: $=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\bar{x}=\bar{y},charK\neq2,3\\ 
\bar{x},charK=3\\ 
\bar{y},charK=2
\end{matrix}\right.$

May I ask how we calculated the residue classes in these situations.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The main tool is Groebner bases here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is their any algebraic system or code would help me computing groebner basis, as I tried singular.uni-kl.de but I think I identified the ring wrong as the result i get is 1